# Flutter theme not applied to new screen

Tags: flutter, dart, themes, navigator

Below is a simple screen with three buttons with different colored themes what I want is when any of each button pressed detail screen should use that theme.

also, I don't what to change the theme of MaterialAppWidget because it's used in other places just this details screen needs to be themed according to which button it opened.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(const App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        home: const HomeScreen(),
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.orange,
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(primarySwatch: Colors.orange),
        ),
      );
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Wrap(
          spacing: 20,
          direction: Axis.vertical,
          children: const [
            ThemedButton(
              materialColor: Colors.red,
            ),
            ThemedButton(
              materialColor: Colors.green,
            ),
            ThemedButton(
              materialColor: Colors.brown,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ThemedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final MaterialColor materialColor;

  const ThemedButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.materialColor,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        primaryColor: materialColor,
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(primarySwatch: materialColor),
      ),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const DetailScreen(),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: const Text('Go to Detail Screen'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DetailScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
class ThemedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  
  final MaterialColor materialColor;
  const ThemedButton({Key? key, required this.materialColor}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        primary: materialColor
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Theme(
              data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                primaryColor: materialColor,
                colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(primarySwatch: materialColor),
              ),
              child: const DetailScreen()
            )
          ),
        );
      },
      child: const Text('Go to Detail Screen'),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm wrapping the Elevated Button in a Builder Widget to use the new BuildContext theme to pass down.

Comment: its working as i want but can u explain why i need to use Builder because as i have read that builder is used when we don't have the context that we want to use but i have already a themed context before `ThemedButton` also why i need to resue `Theme` if parent widget already have themed applied

Comment: I realized there was a tad better way to do this so I edited my answer! From my understanding, Navigating to a new screen will revert back to your global theme in Material App. You already have the right idea, you just needed to wrap the Theme widget in the builder function of MaterialPageRoute